# How many functions are from $\{1,2,...,k\}$ to $\{1,2,...,n\}$ under certain conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many functions are there such that -  $\{1,2,...,k\} \rightarrow\{1,2,...,n\} $
>
> Which satisfy $f(i) - f(i+1) \ge 2$ for all $i \in \{1,..,k-1\},$ and $f(1) = n, f(k)=1$ ?
>
> Also - $n \ge 2k$

**My attempt -**

We can think of that question in combinatorics mind such that, we need to pick $k-2$ (1, k already picked) from a group the size of $n-2$ (1, n already taken). After the random pick, it's only to sort by size to make it monotonic

So (for no conditions..) - $$\binom{n-2}{k-2}$$

Now, what's left to do is to remove all options of consecutive numbers (because of $f(i) - f(i+1) \ge 2$). Couldn't think of a neat way of doing that..

Any thoughts ?

Comment: The condition $n \geq 2k$ follows from the first condition, do you see why?

Comment: I do, actually $n \ge 2k+1$ isn't it ?
Still struggling to understand Ross's answer way of thinking.. @M.Van

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting $n$ balls into $k$ bins with one ball in bin $k$ and at least two balls in each other bin.  $f(i)$ counts the balls in bin $i$ and all the bins to the right.  Start with the minimum number of balls in each bin, which would have $f(1)=2k-1$.  You need to add $n-2k+1$ more balls to some of the bins except the last, so you are looking for the number of [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $n-2k+1$ into $k-1$ parts, of which there are ${n-k-1 \choose k-2}$.

Comment: I don't think i fully understand your solution..
When did you refer to the fact that $f(1) = n$ ? Why did you use f(i) to count the balls in bin $i$ and all the bins to the right ?
Thank you!

Comment: I use $f$ to count the balls to the right as a way to incorporate the rule that $f$ decrease by $2$ at each step.  I am making a bijection between the functions $f$ that meet your requirements and the distributions of balls that can result from this process.  Then I get $f(1)=n$ when I put the extra $n-2k+1$ balls to make the total $n$.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very nice solution.